# Plot multiple bar graph of multiple pandas dataframe columns generated in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, matplotlib

I have a list of data frames, called `listofdf`. It contains 5 data frames, and within each data frame, I am trying to print a barchart of 2 of the columns in a certain size. This should produce a total of 10 charts. I am trying to plot 10 separate plots using a single for loop, I tried subplots in the code below because I couldn't find any way to do separate plots but separate plots would be ideal.

The columns all contain normal numerical data and I can plot them if I do,

```
listofdf[0]['col1'].plot(kind='bar', figsize=(20,5))
```

so the data should be fine.

Here is my code I am trying to use to iterate over the all the data frames and the columns I want to display within the data frames,

```
plotsperloop = 2
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=len(listofdf)*plotsperloop, ncols=1)

for idx, df in enumerate(listofdf):
    idxcount = idx * plotsperloop
    ax[idxcount].plot(df['col1'],kind='bar', figsize=(20,5))
    ax[idxcount+1].plot(df['col2'],kind='bar', figsize=(20,5))
    #plt.show()

plt.show()
```

However, I am unable to select the `kind` as `bar`. I have tried adding the argument `kind = 'bar'` inside the plot method, but I keep getting an error `AttributeError: 'Line2D' object has no property 'kind'`.

If I don't include the `kind` and `figsize` arguments, I am able to display multiple line graphs in a column. But I need them to be bar graphs of a certain size.

I also tried,

```
for df in listofdf:
    df.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(20,5))
```

but I only get 1 plot instead of 10.

What is the proper way to print multiple dynamically generated data frames as plots like this?

Comment: I find this question rather confusing. Do you expect [one figure with 10 subplots](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html?highlight=subplots) in one column? Or 10 figures? Or something else?

Comment: I would like 10 figures (meaning 10 different plots) one after the other if that's possible, I couldn't find anything that could do that so I tried doing subplots